# memoir caption numbering with capital letter and no parenthesis

Tags: memoir, subfloats

Using memoir and `\subtop{}`, I would like to have subfigure identifiers (no caption, just the identifiers) as “A”, “B”, … (caps, no parenthesis).

The MWE below produces almost what I want, but:

- The subfigure identifiers still have parenthesis.
- The capital letter in the identifiers is being faked with large small caps (`\scshape\large`).
- The positioning of the subfigure identifiers to the left of the figure is a ugly hack.

Any help to improve my MWE (or a new cleaner solution) will be appreciated.

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newsubfloat{figure} % allows to use "subbottom"

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[h]
  \subcaptionlabelfont{\hspace*{-.5\textwidth}\scshape\large}
  \centering
    \subtop[]{%
      \parbox{0.4\textwidth}{\blindtext}
    }
    \hfill
    \subtop[]{%
      \parbox{0.4\textwidth}{\blindtext}
    }
  \caption{caption}
  \label{fig:menina}
\end{figure}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of MWE]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newsubfloat{figure} % allows to use "subbottom"
\shortsubcaption % remove it if you want subcaption centered instead
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}


\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[h]
      \subtop[]{%
      \parbox{0.4\textwidth}{\blindtext}
    }    
    \hfill
    \subtop[]{%
      \parbox{0.4\textwidth}{\blindtext}
    }
  \caption{caption}
  \label{fig:menina}
\end{figure}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```